# Solr 6.6.6 installed on Debian 11 automatically shuts down without errors

Tags: solr, debian, django-oscar

I'm running Django-Oscar 3.2 on Debian 11 with solr 6.6.6 and openJDK8.
But when starting solr as a service after a couple of hours solr stops autmaticalliy without any form of error message. I just see the following in the syslog and in the /var/solr/logs/solr.log

2023-08-13 21:36:13.799 INFO  (Thread-0) [   ] o.a.s.c.CoreContainer Shutting down

```
CoreContainer instance=884452399
2023-08-13 21:36:13.799 INFO  (Thread-0) [   ] o.a.s.m.SolrMetricManager Closing metric reporters for: solr.node
2023-08-13 21:36:13.800 INFO  (Thread-0) [   ] o.a.s.m.SolrMetricManager Closing metric reporters for: solr.jvm
2023-08-13 21:36:13.800 INFO  (Thread-0) [   ] o.a.s.m.SolrMetricManager Closing metric reporters for: solr.jetty
2023-08-13 21:36:13.804 INFO  (coreCloseExecutor-13-thread-1) [   x:*] o.a.s.c.SolrCore [petitelite]  CLOSING SolrCore org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore@68df4d4b
2023-08-13 21:36:13.809 INFO  (coreCloseExecutor-13-thread-1) [   x:*] o.a.s.m.SolrMetricManager Closing metric reporters for: solr.core.*
```

Does any body else have the same issue or experienced this before?

Tried rebuilding the core but did not have any effect created a solr service in systemd but stille the same issue occures